# Position of objects in relativelayout

Tags: android, position, android-relativelayout, android-scroll

I'm a beginner in Android. I use Eclipse to program my app. When I create an .xml class and I want to set the specific position of a button, I use this code for example:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fm"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="end" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:scrollX="100dp"
    android:scrollY="30dp"
    android:text="@string/edad" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

... but nothing happens. It sets the button in a corner. How can I get it to appear elsewhere?

Comment: try reading the docs before asking. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use

```
android:layout_marginRight
android:layout_marginLeft 
android:layout_marginTop
android:layout_marginBottom
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use positioning parameters such as android:layout_below.  See the [Relative Layout Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should click the button and go property. That's where the diffrent positioning settings are located. 
For example below :@+id/VIEW then set marin top : 10dip. This will set you button 10 dip below VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:text="@string/edad" />
```